# Question on a specific relation between rational and transcendental numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, transcendental-numbers

Heuristically, the below theorem/conjecture makes sense to me, but I do not have a formal mathematical proof to it; what I am actually looking for. May you perhaps, help with a formal *proof* or *disproof*?

*Definition*

We call a number *definite*, if it has a terminating decimal *(primitively followed by only and only nil digits)*; otherwise, we call the number *indefinite*. For example: $8/11=0.727272...$ and $\sqrt2=1.41421356237...$ are *indefinite*, however, $124.234[0000000...]$ is *definite*.

***Theorem***

Let $q$ be a *definite* rational number and $\tau$ a transcendental number.

If

$$q \; x \; = \; \tau $$

then $x$ is always an *indefinite* real number. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Show that all definite numbers are rational. Then go by contradiction, if $x$ was definite, then you would have that $qx$ is the product of two rational numbers and hence rational, but then $\tau$ would be rational which contradicts it being transcendental.

Comment: According to the definition above, a rational number can be indefinite if its decimals repeat (except of nil.)

Comment: I agree, I am saying that definite implies rational (I am not saying that rational implies definite)

Comment: It is clear that a definite number is one of the form $\frac{n}{10^k}$ for some $k\geq 0$, so a definite number is rational.

Comment: How is "definite" different from "terminating in base 10"?